# How to initialize baseVal of svg viewBox attribute without setAttribute

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm manipulating viewBox of svg using its `viewBox.baseVal` e.g

```
     svgDoc.viewBox.baseVal.x += 10
```

But before I can do that I must initialize it somehow, and to do that I'm using this:

```
    svgDoc.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 1 1')
```

**How do I directly initialize viewBox attribute without setAttribute method?**

ViewBox should be of type that implements [SVGAnimatedRect](http://devdocs.io/dom/svganimatedrect) but I don't know how to create one, I've only found how to create [SVGRect](http://devdocs.io/dom/svgrect) which is type of `viewBox.baseVal`

Comment: There is no other way than setAttribute.

Comment: That is disappointing

Comment: How so, you can set the viewBox initially in markup or with setAttribute, why is that a problem?

Comment: It is not problem per se, but it add unnecessary  complexity - I have to keep track of what attribute e.g. `viewBox'` need special initialization.